# Can I delete a form instance in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a simple edit form, and my idea was to add a delete button to the form, and use this in my view.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = myform(request.POST,instance=myobject)
    if request.POST.get('delete'):
        form.delete()
    else:
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
```

This doens't work. Can I delete this way and do I have an error, or should I do a query first, and then delete the data `Mydata.objects.get(id=id).delete()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot call `delete()` on (what looks like) a `ModelForm`, `myform`.

To delete the instance you will still need to call the model manager by the second way: 
`Mydata.objects.get(id=id).delete()`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot delete that way. You need to get the instance, by querying and delete it.

Also, your way of creating form `form = myform(request.POST,instance=formdata)` is not appropriate. `instance` should to be object not data posted in `request.POST`.

Comment: You are right about the formdata like I put it here (for providing an example). The name formdata is badly chosen, but in my case it is an object. Thanks for pointing this out. I will edit the posting.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can. Just do form.instance.delete()
This is possible since you are passing myobject as instance.
**Edit:** On a second thought it's kind of pointless since you can do myobject.delete() as well.